# Socket.io events on room creation and deletion

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Is there any event associated with the creation and deletion of rooms in socket.io? I want to emit an event to all clients whenever a room is created or deleted.

Comment: I don't think so as new rooms are only created by *you* so why should you get notified?

Comment: @JonasWilms any event associated with the deletion of rooms? currently, I'm using a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no events for room creation and deletion.  Since rooms are only created with `.join()` on the server, you could just create your own function for join and call it everywhere and it could check if the room already exists before calling `.join()`.  If it didn't already exist, it's getting created now.

You could do something similar for `.leave()` with your own function that checks if the room still exists after calling `.leave()`.  If not, then the room was just deleted.

FYI, you can inspect the code yourself for how it works.

Here's the [code for `.join()`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L236) and the [code it calls in the adapter for `.addAll()`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-adapter/blob/master/index.js#L56).

And, the actual room creation is on [this line](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-adapter/blob/master/index.js#L61) with:

```
this.rooms[room] = this.rooms[room] || Room();
```

There are no event notifications triggered in either place.

Answer (score 0):

As I need to maintain some data synced with room state, I had the same problem: how to know when a room is destroyed in order to delete my associated data and avoid memory leaks ?

According to this official doc https://socket.io/fr/docs/v4/adapter/#api, you can easily do some actions on life cycle of a room like this :

```
io.of("/").adapter.on("create-room", (room) => {/*your action*/}
io.of("/").adapter.on("delete-room", (room) => {/*your action*/}
io.of("/").adapter.on("join-room", (room) => {/*your action*/}
io.of("/").adapter.on("leave-room", (room) => {/*your action*/}
```